# Not able to create drop down in HTML

Tags: css, html

I am writing a simple drop down menu code in HTML. I am not able to create dropdown. I am using google chrome. Every thing seems to be displaying fine only the drop down related to `Home3` which is `home3.1` is not showing up. Please help!

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome to I</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="n.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="nav">
        <div id = "nav_wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Home1</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Home2</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Home3</a>       
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home3.1</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////
css file

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

#nav
{
    background-color: #222;
}
#nav_wrapper
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover{
background-color: #333;
}

#nav ul li a,visited
{
color: #ccc;
display: block;
padding : 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ui li a:hover{
color: #ccc;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li: hover ul{
display: block;
}
#nav ul ul{
display: none;
position : absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative` to `#nav ul li` and set the child ul `100%` from the top, then give it a background-color in this case the same as the nav.

Then give the child `ul` an absolute position

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

#nav
{
    background-color: #222;
}
#nav_wrapper
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; /*add this*/
}
#nav ul li:hover{
background-color: #333;
}

#nav ul li a,visited
{
color: #ccc;
display: block;
padding : 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ui li a:hover{
color: #ccc;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover >ul{
display: block;
background: #222;
}
#nav ul ul{
display: none;
position : absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome to I</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Spring Semester\IP\Lab02\test\n.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="nav">
        <div id = "nav_wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Home1</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Home2</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Home3</a>       
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home3.1</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why we added`position: relative` in `#nav ui li`

Comment: @tanz The relative positioning on the parent  will wrap for children with position absolute.

Comment: Because of the way absolute positioning works: It looks for the next parent element whose position is non-static. The browser then refers the top, left, bottom, right positions to the position of that container.

Comment: One last thing, `#nav ul li:hover >ul` why we used this greater than sign. Is it used to tell the compiler that it should apply the corresponding features when ul count is more than 1. I mean when we reach second ul( sub part of original ul)

Comment: @tanz the greater than sign means apply style only  on `direct child` in this case the `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

Try below CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

#nav
{
    background-color: #222;
}
#nav_wrapper
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover{
background-color: #333;
}

#nav ul li a
{
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding : 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ui li a:hover{
    color: #ccc;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul ul{
    display: none;
    position : absolute;
}
#nav ul ul li a{
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/ynn0drp1/3/)**

**[MUTLI-LEVEL MENU](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/ynn0drp1/4/)**

**[MULTI-LEVEL MENU WITH HOVER EFFECT](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/ynn0drp1/5/)**

Comment: Updated URL, Just check it

Comment: What about the hover background-color fix that and you have my +1

Comment: Updated multi-level menu URL also. you have to adjust left position based on you menu size

Comment: I mean hover on li child from `Home3` see OP fiddle or my answer, regards